# Exporting graphs from R in pdf format

Tags: r

I was trying to export the graph after executing the following code:

```
data=read.csv("[data.csv")
library(rpart)
data.rpart=rpart(Sp~X1+X2+X3+X4, data=data)
plotcp(data.rpart)
printcp(data.rpart)
data.rpart1=prune(data.rpart, cp=0.047)
myplot=plot(data.rpart1,uniform=TRUE)
text(data.rpart1, use.n=TRUE, cex=0.6)
data.rpart

dev.copy(pdf,'my plot.pdf')
dev.off()

> dev.copy(pdf,'my plot.pdf')
pdf   #warning
  3 
> dev.off()
windows # warning
      2
```

I did not get any pdf in my working directory. Please advise.
**I have used the iris data set here.

Comment: Look into R studio, it has a panel that shows graphs and you can then export them as pdf or any other image type (tiff, jpg, etc)

Comment: We don't have your data.  Could you instead make this reproducible by including sample data from the `rpart` package instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. (Note the use of `dev.copy2pdf` and the explicit use of `file=`.)

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
data=iris
library(rpart)
data.rpart=rpart(Sepal.Width ~., data=data)
data.rpart1=prune(data.rpart, cp=0.047)
myplot=plot(data.rpart1,uniform=TRUE)
text(data.rpart1, use.n=TRUE, cex=0.6)
dev.copy2pdf(file="my-plot.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works now. However, the texts don't come out completely. Is it possible to re-size the graph before export to see the labels properly?

Comment: try `dev.copy2pdf(file="my-plot.pdf", width=5)` reducing the width parameter makes the text comparatively larger.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(1000)
pdf("myGraph")
hist(x)
dev.off()
```

saves myGraph.pdf to your working directory,